# GDAL Inverse Coordinate Translation

Tags: gdal, c#, ogr, gdal-translate, .net

I have data in WGS84 and when I translate it to ED50 it doesn't appear in the correct place using GDAL and C#. I use CoordinateTransformationOptions.SetOperation using c# to set the specific transformation I need to use.

In the documentation it says -

> bool SetCoordinateOperation(const char *pszCT, bool bReverseCT) Sets
> a coordinate operation.
>
> This is a user override to be used instead of the normally computed
> pipeline.
>
> The pipeline must take into account the axis order of the source and
> target SRS.
>
> The pipeline may be provided as a PROJ string (single step operation
> or multiple step string starting with +proj=pipeline), a WKT2 string
> describing a CoordinateOperation, or a
> “urn:ogc:def:coordinateOperation:EPSG::XXXX” URN
>
> Since GDAL 3.0
>
> Parameters pszCO – PROJ or WKT string describing a coordinate
> operation
>
> bReverseCO – Whether the PROJ or WKT string should be evaluated in the
> reverse path

but in the C# SWIG there is no bReverseCo parameter...

If I use gdaltransform with the transformation I need and the -i switch, it translates from WGS84 to the correct ED50 coordinates, without, it spits out the same coordinates as my code.

Here's some coordinates

| WGS84 (EPSG:4326) | ED50 (EPSG:4230) | ED50 correct (EPSG:4230) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2.25661712354279 56.4136492649363 | 2.25511244583886 56.4129769077511 | 2.25812179682132 56.414321584992 |
| 2.26079813046949 56.4038502877669 | 2.25929393830551 56.4031776339116 | 2.26230231822042 56.4045229044997 |

I use a URN for the transformation -

urn:ogc:def:coordinateOperation:EPSG::1311

I'm using GDAL v3.4.3 latest from NUGET.

Comment: How far out is it? Can you list some inputs and outputs that you are getting?

Comment: @Spacedman I've updated the post with Coordinates

Comment: I don't think its the problem but the ED50 code is 4230, not "4320" as in your table. https://epsg.io/4230

Comment: @Spacedman whoops I put in the wrong EPSG codes in the amended question, fixed it now thanks